# hg grep --exclude pattern

Tags: mercurial, grep

How do you specify the `--exclude`/`-X` parameter when using `hg grep`?

I've tried every kind of bare and pattern syntax I've ever come across (including a few regex dialects I know), but I can't even get it to work with the most simple example.

I'm mostly interested in filtering out some binary files and minified JavaScript files (`*.min.js`) from the search.

I'm on Windows, if that's pertinent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`hg help patterns`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/patterns).  By default, the pattern is treated as a shell glob.

If you want to use a regular expression, you can try something like this:

```
hg grep -X "re:.*\.min\.js$" <search term>
```

Comment: Perfect answer; thank you! Google Search failed me in producing a link to that page.

Comment: Forget google search `hg help` would have gotten you there very quickly.

Comment: @Ry4an: I know that now yes. I did read `hg help` furiously, but didn't notice the `hg help patterns` section. A note in the `hg help grep` section ("see: hg help patterns") would've been beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

`hg help patterns` explains that `Globs are rooted at the current directory; a glob such as "*.c" will only match files in the current directory ending with ".c".`  So to match any file with an extension `.min.js` using a glob you'll need a leading wildcard like `--exclude '**/*.min.js'`